# How to directly access passed POST parameter on PHP file (without json_decode(file_get_contents(PHP: //input)))?When Request Generated By Fetch API?

Tags: php, react-native, fetch-api

example of fetch Request code which i used is shown below:-

```
fetch('https://www.example.com/get_data.php',{
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        test_param: 'test_param_value'
      }),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies,
          desc: responseJson.description,
        },function(){
          console.log(responseJson);
        }
      );
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.log("come on error");
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Server File where request fired by me which contain show below code :-

**get_data.php**

```
<?php
    $test_value = $_POST['test_param'];
    $modify_data = $test_value." some modification";
    echo json_encode($modify_data);
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `php://input` ?  You should be setting the correct content type header for json  `header('Content-type: application/json')`  Otherwsie how can the server know what the data is?  All requests and responses are strings, everything even PDF, images etc. it's the headers that make those strings special.  I don't know if setting the headers alone will fix it, been a long time sense I had to do something like this...

Comment: This doesn't look codeignitery at all. No index.php in url - direct php not wrapped in a class... does this have anything to do with CI?